# how to reactive the lost mode on iPhone 5

Tags: iphone

I upgraded my phone to iPhone 6 and in the process of erasing data etc on my iPhone 5, i somehow put the lost mode in find my phone.  I have since sold my iPhone 5 and now it is still linked to my current apple id.  How do i deactivate the lost mode lock on my old phone?

Answer (score -1):

It's explained in http://support.apple.com/kb/ph2702:

**Remove an iOS device you no longer have**

If you no longer have the iOS device because you gave it away or sold it, you need to remotely erase it before you can remove it.

1. Sign in to icloud.com/#find with your Apple ID (the one you use with iCloud).

   If you’re using another iCloud app, click the app’s name at the top of the iCloud.com window, then click Find My iPhone.
2. Click All Devices, then select the device.
3. Click Erase [device], then enter your Apple ID password. Because the device isn’t lost, don’t enter a phone number or message.

   If the device is offline, the remote erase begins the next time it’s online. You’ll receive an email when the device is erased.
4. When the device is erased, click Remove from Account.

   All your content is erased and someone else can now activate the device.